# insert data into elasticsearch using logstash and visualize in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, date-parsing

I have the following CSV file

```
tstp,voltage_A_real,voltage_B_real,voltage_C_real  #header not present in actual file
2000-01-01 00:00:00,2535.53,-1065.7,-575.754
2000-01-01 01:00:00,2528.31,-1068.67,-576.866
2000-01-01 02:00:00,2528.76,-1068.49,-576.796
2000-01-01 03:00:00,2530.12,-1067.93,-576.586
2000-01-01 04:00:00,2531.02,-1067.56,-576.446
2000-01-01 05:00:00,2533.28,-1066.63,-576.099
2000-01-01 06:00:00,2535.53,-1065.7,-575.754
2000-01-01 07:00:00,2535.53,-1065.7,-575.754
....
```

I am trying to insert the data into elasticsearch through logstash and have the following logstash config

```
input {
    file {
        path => "path_to_csv_file"
        sincedb_path=> "/dev/null"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        columns => [
          "tstp",
          "Voltage_A_real",
          "Voltage_B_real",
          "Voltage_C_real"
        ]
        separator => ","
        }
    date {
        match => [ "tstp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
    }
    mutate {
        convert => ["Voltage_A_real", "float"]
        convert => ["Voltage_B_real", "float"]
        convert => ["Voltage_C_real", "float"]
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        action => "index"
        index => "temp_load_index"
    }
}
```

My output from rubydebug when I run `logstash -f conf_file -v` is

```
{
           "message" => "2000-02-18 16:00:00,2532.38,-1067,-576.238",
          "@version" => "1",
        "@timestamp" => "2000-02-18T21:00:00.000Z",
              "path" => "path_to_csv",
              "host" => "myhost",
              "tstp" => "2000-02-18 16:00:00",
    "Voltage_A_real" => 2532.38,
    "Voltage_B_real" => -1067.0,
    "Voltage_C_real" => -576.238
}
```

However I see only 2 events in kibana when I look at the dashboard and both have the current datetime stamp and not that of the year 2000 which is the range of my data. Could someone please help me figure out what is happening?

A sample kibana object is as follows

```
{
  "_index": "temp_load_index",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "myid",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "2000-04-02 02:00:00,2528.76,-1068.49,-576.796",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-09-27T05:15:29.753Z",
    "path": "path_to_csv",
    "host": "myhost",
    "tstp": "2000-04-02 02:00:00",
    "Voltage_A_real": 2528.76,
    "Voltage_B_real": -1068.49,
    "Voltage_C_real": -576.796,
    "tags": [
      "_dateparsefailure"
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1474953329753
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1474953329753
  ]
}
```

Comment: The two events you are seeing in Kibana have the `_dateparsefailure` tag, so it means that the `tstp` field could not be parsed, so the `@timestamp` field was not replaced with the value from the logs, leaving the time at which Logstash received the log.

Answer (score 0):

When you open Kibana, it usually show you only events in the last 15 min, according to the `@timestamp` field. So you need to set the time filter to the appropriate time range (cf [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/discover.html#set-time-filter)), in your case, using the absolute option and starting 2000-01-01.

Or you can put the parsed timestamp in another field (for example `original_tst`), so that the `@timestamp` added by Logstash will be kept.

```
date {
    match => [ "tstp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
    target => "original_tst"
}
```